# Failed to load resource: the server answered with a popularity of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

hello friend this is my javascript code

```
let baseurl = "https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins"
let proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
let api = "coinrankingea6824d71f28799e230f659ab8dace4ec35215d50fbe8db3"

fetch(`${proxy}${baseurl}`,{
method:"GET",
headers:{
'Content-Type':'application/json',
'x-access-token': `${api} `,
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':`*`
 }

}).then((response)=>{
if (response.ok) {
    response.json().then((json)=>{
        console.log(json);
    })
}
else{
    console.log("error");
}
}).catch((error)=>{

console.log(error);
})
```

and this is my output `GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.coinranking.com/v2/coins 403 (Forbidden)`

please help me solved this error

Comment: it works on my browser, so maybe you send too many requests? I saw if I send too many( 50 per 60 minutes), I get 403 on other origins, this is more about the API than about js...

Answer (score 0):

you sent too many requests(50 per 60 minutes) this is more about the API than about js

the first origin:
[image]

other origin:
[image]

[image]

note the origin change